# Formatting negative numbers with regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to format my numbers and I am using regex /(?=(?!^)(?:\d{3})+$)/g, to replace and insert , where it is necessary. But currently I have an issue with negative {3} 000 numbers, so comma is added after minus.

What am I doing wrong?

```js
'-200'.replace(/(?=(?!^)(?:\d{3})+$)/g, ',')

returns: -,200
correct: -200

'-2000'.replace(/(?=(?!^)(?:\d{3})+$)/g, ',')
returns: -2,000
correct: -2,000
```

Comment: regex seems like an overkill solution for this.

Comment: I know, but there is an issue with a library that I use, and this is the current regex. I am not an expect in regex generation, so I need help here.

Comment: Maybe try giving [this](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-numberformatter/) as shot?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to replace `^` with `\b`

```
(?=(?!\b)(?:\d{3})+$)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/fM1uX7/1)

`(?!^)` asserts that we are not at the start only, but `(?!\b)` asserts that we are not between a word char and a non-word character (*vice-versa*).

**Example:**

```js
alert('-200'.replace(/(?=(?!\b)(?:\d{3})+$)/g, ','))
alert('-2000'.replace(/(?=(?!\b)(?:\d{3})+$)/g, ','))
```

Comment: Use `\B` to negate `\b`.

Comment: @nhahtdh ya, i know.later only i realized.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex:

```
var num = '-2000';
var repl = num.replace(/(\d)(?=(?:\d{3})+$)/m, '$1,');
```

or

```
var repl = num.replace(/(?=(?:\B\d{3})+$)/m, ',');
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dG5pA9/3)

Answer (score 0):

To handle signed numbers, I'd recommend using something else than a regex

```
function formatInteger(num) {
    var str = ('' + num).split('.')[0];
    var sign = (str.charAt(0) === '-') && '-' || '';

    if (sign) {
        str = str.substr(1);
    }

    return sign + str.split('').reduceRight(function (result, char) {
       if (result.length % 4 === 0) {
           char += ',';
       }

       return char + result;
    }, '').slice(0, -1);
}
```

If you feed this function a float, it will be truncated.

```
formatInteger(123456.123); // "123,456"
formatInteger(-1594504924) // "-1,594,504,924"
```

Answer (score 0):

An other way:

```
var nb = '-2000000';
nb = nb.split(/\B/).reduce(function(p, c, i, a) {
    return p + ((a.length-i)%3 ? c : ',' + c);
});
```